# How to transport via flowing water, first horizontally and then upward?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to create a flowing water transportation path. This path should transport items and drop them horizontally and then upward. I can create these if they are independent, but how can I link them together?

Here is what I have tried so far. I want the items to flow into the upwards elevator, but they stop where the signs are, and don't make it in.

[image: a trial of flowing water transportation ( horizontal -> upward )]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the floor blocks with any type of ice. Items slide better on ice and will slide right into the soul sand elevator.

Blue Ice is the best because items slide the fastest. It is more expensive though, so if you're in Survival and don't have any blue ice handy, then Packed Ice will work as an alternative, which is slightly slower, but still works. If you can't get any Packed Ice, you can use Ice, but note that it will melt if placed near a light source.

Learn more about the different types of Ice on the Minecraft Wiki: [Ice (disambiguation)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ice_(disambiguation))